# Mysqli - #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id,firstName,lastName, SUM(qty*price) 
       FROM orders,menu,customers  
       WHERE menu.id = orders.id_menu 
         AND orders.id_customer = customers.id 
 GROUP BY (id,firstName,lastName) 
 ORDER BY (SUM(qty*price)) LIMIT 1;
```

## 1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

i need to get the best customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple rules when writing SQL:

- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Always use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.
- Always alias your tables with abbreviations.
- Always qualify your column references.

Your resulting queries are more likely to work the first time:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, SUM(o.qty * m.price)
FROM orders o JOIN
     menu m
     ON m.id = o.id_menu JOIN
     customers c 
     ON  c.id = o.id_customer
GROUP BY c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName
ORDER BY SUM(o.qty * m.price)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I think #4 should be  "Always qualify *column* references"

Comment: i need to add this condition DATE(date) = CURDATE() , how ?

Comment: @ER-Code . . . You would add a `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score -1):

Change the query to this

```
SELECT customers.id,firstName,lastName, SUM(qty*price) FROM orders,menu,customers  WHERE menu.id = orders.id_menu AND orders.id_customer = customers.id GROUP BY (customers.id,firstName,lastName) ORDER BY (SUM(qty*price)) LIMIT 1;
```

I believe all these tables have column called 'id' and you need to specify which one you need otherwise it will give you this message.

Answer (score -1):

You have many columns as name 'id' in different tables so mysql can not know where is it from (menu.id vs customer.id).

Answer (score -1):

change to:

```
SELECT id,firstName,lastName, SUM(qty*price) 
   FROM orders,menu,customers  
   WHERE menu.id = orders.id_menu 
     AND orders.id_customer = customers.id 
GROUP BY (orders.id,firstName,lastName) 
ORDER BY (SUM(qty*price)) LIMIT 1;
```

you want orders.id as those will be associated with qty and price